# QJsonObject how to create function

Tags: c++, qt, qjsonobject

I know how to create members and values in a QJsonObject.  What I want to do is create a Json function that when called will call the assigned function.

Is this possible?

Comment: JSON is **not JavaScript** and does not have “functions”. JSON could be used to store a *string* representing a (JavaScript or whatever) “function”..

Comment: Yes it does in JavaScript which is where JSON came from.

Comment: That is an incorrect conclusion. Please visit http://json.org so that you can start spreading correct, validated, information. Aside from some similarities with JS Object syntax, JSON is not JavaScript/ECMAScript.

Comment: What’s the actual use-case? There are ways to embed a JS engine. Or maybe it not needed anyway.. also, consider that the goal might be to generate JavaScript *instead of* JSON.

Comment: According to the specification JSON can contain objects.  An object is not just a collection of data types, an object contains methods.

Comment: FYI @SPlatten, context of words is important. I’m done ‘debating’ a Kelly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is not possible, functions are not a valid json value.

Valid json values are : string, number, object, array, boolean or null.

In Qt, valid QJsonValues are:  bool QJsonValue::Bool, QJsonValue::Double, QJsonValue::String, QJsonValue::Array, QJsonValue::Object, QJsonValue::Null

[json spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#page-5)

Comment: Thank you, I’ll wait a bit longer to see if anyone has any suggestions.  It’s a bit of a hole in the implementation of that is really the case.

Comment: And, storing a function in a ' Data Interchange Format' it isn't a good idea

Comment: ,it’s depends on why I want it... I’m developing an engine that will partner objects with scripting.

Comment: Ok, it is like a qt method (Q_INVOKABLE) called from the javascript engine or something like that ?

Comment: Yes, I want to return a QJsonObject back to my scrip which works, I want to assign a function to the JSON which invokes a C++ method.

Comment: But, you can share an existing QObject to the script engine, and all the properties and public slots will be accesible inside javascript. Is not that good for your problem?

Comment: That’s what I’m try to do, question is how?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190172/discussion-between-jgoday-and-splatten).

Comment: Thank you for your time and help, I think I'm on the way to sorting it out now.